# cargar imagen a servidor php y ajax

Tags: php, ajax, servidor

Hola estoy atorado en una aplicación que estoy haciendo.
tengo este código que es para subir una imagen a una carpeta de mi servidor pero a la hora que le doy subir no me sube la imagen solo me muestra el previem algun consejo? algun consejo o ayuda que me pudiera dar o correcion de mi codigo, esto lo quiero implementar un registro a mi pagina pero quiero subir la imagen en el formulario

**INDEX*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".upload").on('click', function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        var files = $('#image')[0].files[0];
        formData.append('file',files);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response != 0) {
                    $(".card-img-top").attr("src", response);
                } else {
                    alert('Formato de imagen incorrecto.');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <h2 class="lead"></h2>



            <form method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="images/default-avatar.png">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Sube una foto</h5>

                        <div class="form-group">

                            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" name="image" id="image">
                        </div>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary upload" value="Subir">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <
</body>
</html>
```

**En esta parte tengo el php que recibe los datos para poder almacenarlos**

```
<?php
if (is_array($_FILES) && count($_FILES) > 0) {
    if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
        || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")) {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$_FILES['file']['name'])) {
            //more code here...
            echo "images/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
        } else {
            echo 0;
        }
    } else {
        echo 0;
    }
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

seria de mucha ayuda que me pudieran asesorar en esto

Comment: 1.- ¿La carpeta `images` existe? 2.- ¿Qué permisos tiene dicha carpeta? 3.- ¿Cuánto pesan las imágenes? 4.- ¿Cuál es el valor de las variables `upload_max_filesize` y `post_max_size`?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que hacer unas modificaciones a código html, javascript y php:

1. Agregarle un `id` a tu form

---

```
<form id="mi-asombroso-form" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

2. Modificar el código jquery a esto:

---

```
$(".upload").on('click', function() {        
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            type: 'post',
            //I. Modificación
            data: new FormData($('#mi-asombroso-form')[0]),
            contentType:false,
            //II. Modificación
            cache:false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(response) {
                //III. Modificación
                if (parseInt(response) != 0) {
                    $(".card-img-top").attr("src", response);
                } else {
                    alert('Formato de imagen incorrecto.');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
});
```

Explico los puntos modificados:

I. [Cambiamos la forma de enviar el formulario como objeto por jquery a php de una manera serializada](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData).

II. [Usamos `cache` como `false` para forzar al navegador a no almacenar caché en ningún momento](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

III. Parseamos el `0` a tipo entero con [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) tu respuesta desde php para que forcemos a que se lea como tal y no como string como ajax lo responde desde php.

3. Tu código php recibe con la variable global [`$_FILES`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php) la información que le pertenece al input de tipo `file` y el resto de tipo de inputs con `$_POST`

---

```
<?php
//esto te servirá para ver qué recibes por parte de tu input `$_FILES`
print_r($_FILES);
//...después va tu código que tienes
```

Es importante también que:

1. Tu carpeta donde guardas las imágenes y las apuntas para guardar en tu `move_uploaded_file` llamada `images` exista en el mismo nivel de tu archivo php. Como una recomendación, siempre ocupa la constante [`__DIR__`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php) para que no haya fallos en encontrar la ruta en el servidor.

Esto quedaría en tu código php de ser esto:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "images/".$_FILES['file']['name'])
```

A esto:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], __DIR__ . "/images/".$_FILES['file']['name'])
```

2. Que la carpeta `images` existente tenga permisos de escritura y lectura